# Argparse: Hiding usage when using argparse.ArgumentTypeError

Tags: python, argparse

Whenever a user doesn't provide suitable parameters to arguments in my script, I raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError with the error string I provided. My problem is that argparse also prints the usage, while it seems irrelevant to me to tell the user how to use my script when he just got a parameter wrong.

Is there a way for certain cases of raising argparse.ArgumentTypeError to suppress the usage printout? Will I need to use a custom usage function? Or maybe I shouldn't be using this exception at all?

Comment: Have you tried something like parser.add_argument('--foo', help=argparse.SUPPRESS), it's in the documentation. It suppress usage of that command. Read the help section. https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#help

Comment: It suppresses mention of *that one argument* from the usage message, @Reticentroot. I interpret this question to be about suppressing the *entire* usage message.

Comment: So then you just add that argument to all of the input arguments resulting in global suppression  @RobKennedy

Comment: That makes for a lousy message when you actually *want* the usage message, though, @Reticentroot, such as when the user gives a nonexistent argument, or requests `--help`. The suppression case is only when a known argument receives an invalid parameter, such as in the documentation where we use `parser.add_argument('foo', type=perfect_square)`, and the user doesn't provide a number that's a perfect square. In that example, we see that the program prints the usage statement *and* the error message. Gabe wants only the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you raising the `ArgumentTypeError`?  In a `type` function?

The definition of `ArgumentTypeError` is just `pass`; it doesn't do anything except subclass `Exception`.

It is referenced in `_get_value`, which calls the `type` function on your argument string.  That method treats `TypeError` and `ValueError` in the same way.  It recasts the error as `ArgumentError`, which adds the argument `dest` (name) to the message.  `parse_known_args` ends up converting that to a call to `parser.error`.

It's the `parser.error` method that adds the `print_usage`.

So simply changing that method might be the solution to your problem.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exiting-methods

I'm not sure what happens if your `type` function returns some other error - it might bubble all the way to the top.

The formal way to change the `parser.error` method is to subclass `ArgumentParser`, but you can kludge a one time change with:

```
In [269]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [270]: def myerror(message):
   .....:     print(message)

In [271]: parser.error=myerror

In [272]: parser.add_argument('foo')
Out[272]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [273]: parser.parse_args([])
the following arguments are required: foo
Out[273]: Namespace(foo=None)
```

This just showed the message, and did not exit.  If I'd stuck closer to the original it would have exited as well.